# Navigation stay Highlight if in current page

Tags: jquery, hover, highlight

well my problem is the next, I got a navigation with a **animation in jQuery**, a green slider that comes down when hover the **< li >** tag.

when is current page, the hightlight state is to stay down, but when I mouseOut it returns to the top, thats the natural behaviour.

I what to know how can I tell jQuery to "if" is $current slide, don't mouseOut

Maybe u can check out the code [better in the website](http://dinterweb.com/conelectricas/)

I got a variable.

**$current** = the current page.

**jQuery Code:**

```
 var navHover = function () {
  $("#S" + this.id).animate({top: '-40px'}, 300, 'swing')
  $("#A" + this.id).animate({paddingTop: '30px'}, 300, 'swing').animate({paddingTop: '45px'}, 300, 'swing')
  $("#I" + this.id).animate({top: '-10px'}, 300, 'swing').animate({top: '0px'}, 300, 'swing')
 }
 var navRelease = function () {
  $("#S" + this.id).animate({top: '-130px'}, 300, 'swing');
 }
 
 $('#navInside .topLevel').hover(navHover, navRelease);
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, I get some help from [ircmaxell](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell)

I add did this after my css in the header so I can get the value of currentPage right.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentPage = "<?php echo substr($current, 1) ?>";
</script>
```

Then change this code to the if statement.

```
 var navRelease = function () {
 if(this.id != currentPage){
 $("#S" + this.id).animate({top: '-130px'}, 300, 'swing');}
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily do this by setting a flag in your JS, something like:

`var currentPage = "nInicio"`

Then in then navHover:

```
 var navHover = function () {
  if(this.id != currentPage){
   $("#S" + this.id).animate({top: '-40px'}, 300, 'swing')
   $("#A" + this.id).animate({paddingTop: '30px'}, 300, 'swing').animate({paddingTop: '45px'}, 300, 'swing')
   $("#I" + this.id).animate({top: '-10px'}, 300, 'swing').animate({top: '0px'}, 300, 'swing')
  }
 }
 var navRelease = function () {
 if(this.id != currentPage){
  $("#S" + this.id).animate({top: '-130px'}, 300, 'swing');
  }
 }
```

My code might not be correct (just typed it psudo like real quick) but it should disable any hover / release actions if your selected id is the one that matches the page. That way it stays 'un-animated'.

**EDIT**

Since you are having trouble with the PHP side of it:

```
<script>
  var current = "<?php echo substr($current, 1) ?>";
</script>
```

**EDIT EVEN MORE...**

Okay it seems you are having trouble adding the

```
<script>
  var current = "<?php echo substr($current, 1) ?>";
</script>
```

in the right place.  I would put this into your main body, as long as it is on the main page right when you open the `<body>`.  I hope that helps, I am starting to feel like you are trying to hack this not knowing any php or javascript.

If you like this answer, please mark as 'answer' (green checkmark) thanks..

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry I'm very new to programing, can you tell me if I can use a PHP to the var, like:

var currentPage = "<php? $current ?>"

Comment: yes, thats exactly what you can do for the page value, except proper code would be `<?php echo $current ?>` (you forgot the echo part).

Comment: Thanks for your help, just something more, the id for the "currentPage" is the id of the slide, 

Example slide id: "SnInicio", and the id for (this) is "nInicio", so how can I remove the S from the value? Thanks for your help

Comment: I try this but didn't work.... 
var currentPage = <?php echo $current ?>;
var current = currentPage.replace(/^.(\s+)?/, "");

Comment: For removing a piece of a string, see `substr` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php.  ;)

Comment: var currentPage = <?php echo substr('$current', 1) ?>; (Ok that is what I try, didn't work, is there a problem if the $current is on my header and the jQuery script its on a .js file in other place? can that affect it to get the value? do I have to post and .get?

Comment: I know some jQuery, a very little php, but I mark your answer with the green check before your "Edit even more" ^^ So don't worry ^^ thanks for the help

Comment: Well as long as you got it working, I was starting to worry that you didn't know how variables worked in javascript/php :P